# Missing a condition

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I have 3 condition :

- if the majority of Average is equal to 200, display "up" into a array
- if the majority of Average is different to 200, display "down" into a array and take the first timestamp where average is different to 200.

And I don't know how can I do the last :

- we compile again the script, if before I have "down" and now the majority is 200 ("up"), we must keep the timestamp and not put it in null.

Can you help me please :)

```
getAllMetrics(regions).then(res => {
console.log(res);
/*
[[{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}],
[{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 400},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 400},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000, Average: 400},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}]] */

/*    SECOND COMPILATION 
[[{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}],
[{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 400},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}]] */
tabRES = [];
//Loop regions
var i = -1;
TsTAB = [null, null, null];

var a=-1;
while( tabReg[++a] ){
    TsTAB.push( null );
}
while (res[++i]) {
    Avg = {
    up: 0,
    down: 0
    };
    Ts = "";
    RespARRAY = res[i];
    var j = -1;
    while (RespARRAY[++j]) {
    if (RespARRAY[j].Average == 200) {
        Avg.up++ // IF 200 -> UP
        //and push array TS
    } else {
        Avg.down++ // -> DOWN
        //Retrieve the last 
        Ts = Ts || RespARRAY[j].Timestamp;
    }
    }
    if (Avg.up > Avg.down) {
    tabRES.push('up');
    } else {
    tabRES.push('down');
    TsTAB[i] = TsTAB[i] || Ts;
    }
}
console.log(tabRES);
console.log(TsTAB);
}).catch(err => {
console.log(err);
});
```

Actual result(first and second condition):

- ['up','down']
- [null,3 days ago]

Expected result (last condition) (/!\ Value of Average change for the second region )

- ['up','up']
- [null, 3 days ago]

Comment: `tabRES` should have only 1 value and not 2, can you provide the full output of your `res` array?

Comment: I have two array in my res, so i have 2 value in my tabRES. 
I put all of output of my res

Comment: Didn't see the hidden array tags in the middle there. you should try to reformat the code to look better

Comment: In the second array you have 3 objects with 400 and 2 with 200, so the actual result is correct, why you think the expected result should be both `up`? you said yourself that if there are more 400 then 200 do down.

Comment: Oh ok; look again my output

Comment: So the result is for the second run and not for the first run?

Comment: Actually, The first result is good but to the second, The value pass 'down' to 'up' beaucause now the majority of average is 200 and I want to save the last timestamp

Comment: @marcillesStanislas I think in the first complation it should be ['up','down'] since there are 3 x '400' and only 2 x '200' in the second response? `[{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 400},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 400},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000, Average: 400},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}]`

Comment: for second compilation, it should be ['up', 'up'] since there are 5 '200's and 4 '200's 1 '400's in each of the results

Answer (score 0):

```js
var res =  [[{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z", Average: 200},
{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000", Average: 200},
{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z", Average: 200},
{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z", Average: 200}],
[{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 400},
{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z", Average: 400},
{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 400},
{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z", Average: 200},
{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z", Average: 200}]];

/*    SECOND COMPILATION 
[[{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}],
[{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 400},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}]] */

let results = res.reduce((acc,resArray) => {
                innerResult = resArray.reduce((_acc,obj) => {
                   if(obj.Average == 200) {
                      _acc.up++;
                   } else {
                      _acc.down++;
                      _acc.time = obj.Timestamp;
                   }
                   return _acc;
                }, { up:0, down:0, time:null });
                
                if(innerResult.up > innerResult.down) {
                  acc.res.push('up');
                  acc.ts.push(null);
                }
                else {
                  acc.res.push('down');
                  acc.ts.push(innerResult.time);
                }
                return acc;
              }, {res:[], ts:[]});
console.log(results.res);
console.log(results.ts);
```